# How to Add Mouse click event to Picturebox using C#.net

Tags: c#, mouseevent

i am creating simple inventory system. i need only this if i click picturebox 1 relavent message should display "pic1" if  i click piturebox 2 relavent message should display "pic2"

[image]

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseClick += mouseClick;

    } 
    private void mouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        var clickedPictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
        if (clickedPictureBox == pictureBox1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Pic1");

        }
    }
```

i tried the code but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're using the form's mouse click event, you'll need to replace:

```cs
this.MouseClick += mouseClick;
```

by:

```cs
pictureBox1.MouseClick += mouseClick;
pictureBox2.MouseClick += mouseClick;
```

**Option 1: Use the sender object**
The mouse click event gives you the argument `sender`, which is the object that triggered the event.
So you could use it like this:

```cs
var clickedPictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
if (clickedPictureBox == pictureBox1)
   ...
```

**Option 2: use a tag**
You can set tags in your winforms elements and use them. For example, go to the Designer and set the tag of both pictures to "Pic1" and "Pic2" and then use it like this:

```cs
var clickedPictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
if (clickedPictureBox.Tag.ToString() == "Pic1")
   ...
```

Comment: message is not displayed

Comment: if i click the pic1

Comment: Take a look at my edit, you are using the form's click event and not the pictures'